# Lattice wireframe does not show mesh

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to plot a 3D graph with lattice. I managed to do a 3D scatterplot, but if I try to plot my graph with the wireframe function the graph appears empty.

[image]

This is a part of my data with which I could reproduce my issue:

```
    structure(list(z = c(35.6848570203496, 20.6910550942398, 36.2505636561432, 
    38.9791450251443, 12.9514876234809, 10.0549459964936, 7.1604652315673, 
    14.681581323841, 29.7104179049907, 8.4814778127832), y = c(21.72, 
    21.72, 21.72, 21.72, 3.57, 3.57, 4.83, 4.83, 4.83, 4.83), x = c(22L, 
    136L, 79L, 23L, 34L, 22L, 16L, 66L, 30L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my code:

```
    wireframe(z~x*y,df, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to interpret these points as a surface? The data for a wireframe should be from a regular grid. It's not clear to me what the desired output is.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use `plotly`: https://plotly.com/r/3d-scatter-plots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolate `df` to a regular grid using `akima::interp`, remove NA's and then use lattice `wireframe`.

```
library(lattice)
library(akima)

i <- with(df, interp(x, y, z, extrap = TRUE))
g <- with(i, expand.grid(x = x, y = y))
df2 <- data.frame(g, z = c(i$z))
wireframe(z~x*y, na.omit(df2), scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]